# VIM Autocomplete sources

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I often use VIM auto-complete (CTRL+N\P) facility, it recognizes enums or defines (string based I guess) that are only in the set of current open files. In order to overcome this, I usually open a header file that contain all the enums\defines in a new tab, and then the auto-complete has all the values.

I wonder if there were a way to include this file in the default set of files that vim looks in when it searches for the auto-complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the default value of the `complete` option, `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` should complete using your include files. You may wish to adjust the `path` option, though (see `:help 'path'`).

You can also use the following command to tell Vim to use `/path/to/file` as a dictionary completion source:

```
:set complete+=k/path/to/file
```

See `:help 'complete'`.

Comment: Thanks romainl, that was exactly what I needed.
Nadav.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider the `'include'` option.  Assuming that `'complete'` includes the `i` flag (which is part of the default), vim will automatically search included files.  The default value of `'include'` recognizes C-style include statements:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

If you are editing some other language, then you may want to choose a different setting, probably in an ftplugin file.

```
:help 'complete'
:help 'include'
:help 'path'
```